# Do $L^2$ functions with essential support have a finite average?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open and bounded domain, and $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, where $f$ is further chosen such that it is essentially supported on $\Omega$.

Question. Is the average of such $f$:
$$\frac{1}{|\Omega|} \int_{\Omega} f\, d\Omega,$$ defined? If not, what should I require of $f$ so that the average is well defined?

Comment: Can you please tell us more about $\Omega$? Is it a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question.

Comment: What is the codomain of $f$? Is it again the reals or perhaps complex numbers?

Comment: For finitely measured space the Lebesgue spaces are decreasing with the exponent, as shown by the Hölder’s inequality (or Jensen’s).

Comment: If the essential support of $f$ is contained in $\Omega$, this means $f$ is zero a.e. outside of $\Omega$. Then you can treat this is a function just defined on $\Omega$ and use Holder's inequality

Comment: @cnikbesku, it's again reals.
blamethelag, and Chris: ok, perfect!

Comment: Yes, and the average is bounded by $|\Omega|^{-1/2}\|f\|_{L^2}$ by Holder’s inequality and the fact that $f = f\chi_\Omega$ almost everywhere.